# How to list all the tags for VM's in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to list all the tags tied to select VM's (or all if that is easier) in Azure. While the az cli is one option (it works fine), since I have so many of them is there a kql query for this I can use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to list all tags related to a VM.

```
AzureActivity
| where ResourceProviderValue == "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
| where ResourceId contains "<VM Resource ID>"
| extend tags = tostring(Properties.Tags)
| project tags
```

You can also remove the where statement about VM Resource ID to display all tags connected to any VM.

Comment: That worked for one vm ! Is there a way to feed it a list of say 800 vms ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it couldn't.